# jQuery embedding youtube IE issue

Tags: jquery

I have been working on a custom image slider featured here:

JQuery

```
$(function(){
      $('.cont:gt(0)').hide();
      $("#parent").on("mouseenter", ".extraContent div", function(){
           var ind = $(this).index();
           $("#parent").find(".cont").stop().fadeTo(600,0,function(){
               $('#parent').find('.cont').eq(ind).stop().fadeTo(300,1);
           });
        });
        $('#parent .extraContent').on('click',function(){
             window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
             return false;
        });
    });
```

CSS

```
​#parent { width:400px; margin:auto}
.mainContent { width:430px; height:300px; border:1px solid #000;padding:5px; }
.extraContent {overflow:auto; width:450px;}
.extraContent div{float:left; width:90px; height:90px; border:1px solid #00F; margin:5px; padding:5px }
.extraContent div:hover { border:1px solid #0F0;cursor:pointer }
.cont{
   position:absolute;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="mainContent">
        <div class="cont"> Content 1....</div>
        <div class="cont"> Content 2....</div>
        <div class="cont">Content 3...<br /><iframe width="267" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6tlQn7iePV4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
        <div class="cont"> Content 4....</div>  
    </div>
    <div class="extraContent">
        <div><p>1 Custom content here <br /> <a href="">Some link</a></p></div>
        <div><p>2 Custom content here <br /> <a href="">Some link</a></p></div>
        <div><p>3 Custom content here <br /> <a href="">Some link</a></p></div>
        <div><p>4 Custom content here <br /> <a href="">Some link</a></p></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

My problem is if I embed YouTube video straight from the site using there iframe it transitions fine in Chrome but Firefox & IE just display the video straight away and each slide/div appears under the video, is this a known problem and doesn't anyone know a way I can get IE & FF to behave.

p.s. because this is going to be in a content management system the only way the user can embed the video is using the default code from youtube.

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vrqdh/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue, I call it "super z-index". It's a flash related problem. If you use the HTML5 player it won't happen. Basically you have to set one more parameter in your Youtube url:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/6tlQn7iePV4?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent
                                              ^--------------------^
```

By the way, if you want to keep your markup clean you can use this snnipet that will transform your Youtube links into iframes, including the z-index fix.

```
function embedYoutube(link, ops) {

  var o = $.extend({
    width: 480,
    height: 320,
    params: ''
  }, ops);

  var id = /\?v\=(\w+)/.exec(link)[1];

  return '<iframe style="display: block;"'+
    ' class="youtube-video" type="text/html"'+
    ' width="' + o.width + '" height="' + o.height +
    ' "src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?' + o.params +
    '&amp;wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" />';
}
```

More info about it [on this article](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/10/04/10-useful-and-time-saving-javascript-snippets/).